# Validation in Entity (ADF)

Tags: java, validation, entity, jdeveloper

Anyone know how to make a column mandatory when column A(Date) greater than column B(Date) within the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Entity-Level Validation of Type Method. Create a Method in the overridden EOImpl for column A(Date) greater than column B(Date) and return false for the case. In the failure handling section of the EO validator, you can include an error message specifying the column as mandatory